# Mocking errors with Symfony4, codeception and AspectMock

Tags: symfony4, codeception, goaop

I've a trouble : 
I need to mock some objects for testing my login WS with Sf4.1.
I've installed codeception and AspectMock.
Unfortunately, I have errors one after the others for well configuring aspectmock.

Firstly, I've tried to simply mock my manager :

My LoginCest:

```
public function postLoginWithLoginForm()
{
    $this->apiTester->wantTo('test login with standard login form');
    $tokenMock = Test::double(
        new LoginManager(),
        LoginHelper::loginFromFormLogin(
            ['_username' => 'FOO', '_password' => 'BAR']
        )
    );
    $this->apiTester->sendPOST(
        $this->router->generate(
            static::MY_ROUTES['form_login']),
        ['_username' => 'FOO', '_password' => 'BAR']
    );
    $tokenMock->verifyInvokedOnce('loginFromFormLogin');
    $this->apiTester->seeResponseIsJson();
    $this->apiTester->seeResponseCodeIs(Response::HTTP_OK);
    $response = json_decode($this->apiTester->grabResponse(), true);
    $this->apiTester->assertArrayHasKey('token', $response);
}
```

LoginHelper :

```
class LoginHelper
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        Test::clean();
    }

    /**
     * @param array $postParameters
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function loginFromFormLogin(array $postParameters): 
string
    {
        if (
            !array_key_exists('_username', $postParameters)
            || !array_key_exists('_password', $postParameters)
        ) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException();
        }

        return '16T3KLDN?LK';
    }
}
```

My controller for the route :

```
/**
 * @Rest\Post("/form/login", name="post_form_login")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function postFormLogin(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $postParameters = $request->request->all();

    $token = $this->loginManager->loginFromFormLogin($postParameters);

    return new JsonResponse(['token' => $token]);
}
```

With that, I've an error on test execution :

```
[Error] Call to a member function registerObject() on null
```

Moreover, I've red this thread concerning more or less my issue : [AspectMock GitHub](https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock/issues/10)

So I've set a bootstrap file under my tests/ directory like that :

```
<?php
$kernel = \AspectMock\Kernel::getInstance();
$kernel->init([
    'appDir'    => __DIR__ . '/../../',
    'cacheDir'  => '/tmp/myapp',
    'includePaths' => [__DIR__.'/../src', __DIR__.'/Helper'],
    'excludePaths' => [__DIR__] // tests dir should be excluded
]);
```

But now, I've always this error :

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
Compile Error: Redefinition of parameter $_
```

Could you help me to manage to mock my tests please ?

Thanks by advance,

Comment: Did you find an answer for this yet?